# Toggle dynamically created tables on div click

Tags: jquery, html, css, razor

I have a View where the `div` associated with the table and the table are created dynamically. I tried using Jquery to hide/show div, but only the first table is being toggled. I have seen examples for applying toggle on table rows but not on the whole table.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="main">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
    <div id="ConfigName">
        <h3><b>@item.ConfigurationCollection.CollectionName</b></h3>
    </div>
    <div id="ConfigDetails" style="display:none">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            @foreach (var lis in item.ListConfiguration)
            {
                <th>@lis.Option.OptionName</th>
            }
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var lis in item.ListConfiguration)
            {
                <td>
                    @foreach (var ov in lis.OptionValue)
                    {
                        @ov.OptionVal
                        <br />
                    }
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    </table>            
    </div>
}
```

Script (Comments include everything I tried)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ConfigName').click(function () {
        //$('#ConfigDetails').slideToggle();
        //$(this).parent().find('#ConfigDetails').slideToggle();
        var closest = $(this).closest().find('#ConfigDetails').is(":visible");
        if(!closest)
        {
            $(this).find('$ConfigDetails').slideToggle();
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: should be .find('#ConfigDetails') not '.find('$ConfigDetails')'. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yeah. It is. With my current code not even the first div toggles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems,

1. Id should be unique. You have multiple elements with same ids. You need to replace it with class
2. `.find('$ConfigDetails')`, in this line you need to use `.` instead of `$`(class selector).

Then your final code will be,

```
 $('.ConfigName').click(function () {
     $(this).next().slideToggle();
 });
```

Note: You should change all the id's into class names, including "configName"

Comment: I changed the id to class. Used . as the selector. Still there are no changes

Comment: Ok. Now it toggles all the tables on a single click.

Comment: What should be the expected behaviour?

Comment: use $(this).next().slideToggle();. see the edited code.